# jquery getting the centre of a slider

Tags: jquery, slider

I am building a jquery slider.

I have `$total_images` (total no. of images) and `$total_length` (in pixels).

I am looking for an elegant solution to start the slider in the dead centre of a slide - but not half way between an image.

If there is an even number of images I can just do `$total_length/2`.

```
$total_images = 10;
$image_length = 400

$startposition = ($total_images * $image_length) / 2
```

the problem is the slider is dynamic - so could contain 11 images.

Thanks,

Comment: Try jQuery Cycle plugin, very stable and does exactly what you need it to.

Comment: I cannot use that. is there an is_odd() function?

Comment: Why not? And no, there is no is_odd function, you will have to calculate if a function is odd by doing so: `number % 2 == 1` returns true if odd. Javascript and PHP are two totally different things, you must also define your variables with the `var` statement before using them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use either `Math.floor` or `Math.ceil` of your calculation to get the closest whole number, less or greater, respectively.

```
var total_images = 10,
    image_length = 400,
    startPosition = Math.floor((total_images * image_length) / 2);
```